# How to add intervals in the X axis using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to get intervals of 10, starting from 0 and going on till 50. But I am getting intervals of 5.

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.12/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis();
        var axisScale = d3.scale.linear()
                   .domain([0,100])
                   .range([0,100]);
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(axisScale);
        typeof(xAxis);
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                  .attr("width", 700)
                                  .attr("height", 100);

        //Create the Scale we will use for the Axis
        var axisScale = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([0, 50])
                      .range([0, 400]);
        //Create the Axis
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(axisScale);
        //Create a group Element for the Axis elements and call the xAxis function
        var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
                                    .call(xAxis);
    </script>
</body>
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most safe way to specify the values in a D3 axis is using `axis.tickValues`. In your case:

```
.tickValues(d3.range(axisScale.domain()[0], axisScale.domain()[1] + 10, 10));
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 700)
  .attr("height", 100);

var axisScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 50])
  .range([0, 400]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(axisScale)
  .tickValues(d3.range(axisScale.domain()[0], axisScale.domain()[1] + 10, 10));

var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20,50)")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```css
path,
line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.12/d3.min.js"></script>
```